# Fréquence relative et caractère usuel de « à propos », « au sujet » « de ce/du document » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, pronoms-personnels, fréquence-utilisation

[image]

Quelle combinaison parmi les suivantes est-elle la plus usuelle/fréquente en gestion documentaire comme titre de section (peut-on les classer par ordre), sont-elles toutes acceptables et peut-on commenter généralement (dans sa réponse) sur la différence entre le partitif et le démonstratif en contexte ?

> *au sujet du document
>
> au sujet de ce document
>
> à propos du document
>
> à propos de ce document*

Comment: Dans quel domaine/contexte ? La "gestion documentaire" ne me semble pas restreindre suffisamment le champ des possibles, et il peut y avoir bien d'autres traductions que celles proposées.

Comment: @guillaume31 Il n'est nullement question de traduction. Uniquement de fréquence de cooccurrence des éléments suggérés. C'est la seule chose qui m'intéresse ici. Le contexte n'est pas pertinent, c'est celui de la méta-information pure., j'ai ramassé le document sur un site suisse parce que le contenu de la section correspond à quelque chose qui m'est connu. C'est pour fins d'illustration uniquement.

Answer (score 1):

There are no possibilities of sources in such a question (unless there are some statistics I have missed). So the following ranking is only my impression.

1. à propos du document
2. à propos de ce document
3. au sujet du document
4. au sujet de ce document

Conclusion: I have thought about the least frequent/"worst sounding" between using the demonstrative "ce" and the locution "au sujet de" in this particular case, and felt like it was "au sujet de". At least in France, "au sujet de" is almost always used in the middle of a sentence after the main verb (rarely in the beginning or on its own like here), e.g.

> Je vous appelle au sujet de l'appartement.

Therefore, anything else than 1. or 2. sounds very unlikely to find. The choice between using the demonstrative or not is not that important, as the document is supposedly clearly identified in this context; skipping the demonstrative feels more natural but not mandatory.

PS: Partitives (partitif) is the "de" used to refer to uncountable elements (*un morceau de pain*). [See here](https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/le-determinant-partitif-f1497). The **de** in *à propos **de** ce document* (which is the same as the one in *à propos **du** document*, with **du** being a contraction of **de** and **le**) is a mere preposition, part of the [prepositional locution "à propos de"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_propos_de).

- Partitive "de" (+ le/la...) has this notion of **part**, part of something **uncountable** (*de l'argent*, *du cyclisme*)
- The "A propos de" locution refers to a noun, countable or not (*à propos des trois documents*, *à propos de la mer*), we're about to introduce
- Demonstratives are placed before the noun they point at (*ce tableau*, *cette danseuse*)